# How can I debug the bash prompt?

Tags: linux, debugging, bash

I've been editing `.bashrc` files and other init files, and it seems that I've left behind a few code snippets or two that are causing a few errors at the prompt (e.g. file missing), but I can't find them.

How do I debug the prompt to find out what init scripts I've carelessly hacked?

Comment: On a pragmatic level, one thing you could do quickly would be to add a dummy user to your machine, and then diff the files created in that account against those in yours.  A more sophisticated plan would be to figure out where the defaults come from, and diff against those.  Of course if you modified system-wide files you would need to find a way to get files out of the install package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most of the shells have debug flags that show the commands being executed. Bash may even have one that shows a command before expansion of variables and after. Have you tried checking (I believe) -c -x or -X flags and see if they show the information you are looking for.

You can set them as first thing in the rc files (most global one) or just pass it down into bash command by invoking it from another shell.

In fact, if you invoke bash from another shell, you can also use *script* command to record everything you see and do into the file, which makes postmortem analysis so much easier.

Comment: After dumping the stuff into a file, a few simple grep's pulled everything I needed.

Answer (score 17):

Try invoking bash with the -x flag, then sourcing your .bashrc or .bash_profile or whatever you're using. That ought to be prolix enough to find your problem

ie:

```
bash -x
source .bashrc
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to get a clean initial state is to SSH into your current host, but instead of letting SSH launch your shell with default settings, you provide an explicit command which prevents `.bashrc` from being read.

```
ssh -tt localhost /bin/bash --norc
```

The `-tt` forces SSH to allocate a TTY, which is what would normally happen when you open a shell connection, but is *not* default when running an explicit command.

The `--norc` prevents bash from reading your settings file (since we want to do that ourselves).

You should now be at a bash prompt, in a *clean* environment. This is useful for examining what variable are set to before your `.bashrc` runs etc. Enable tracing and source your `.bashrc`:

```
set -x   # Enable tracing
source .bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see where you've defined prompt - probably it in some dot file in your home directory:

```
grep PS1 ~/.*
```

You can see current value of prompt by just printing it:

```
echo $PS1
```

HTH

Answer (score -1):

Check the  `.bash_history` file in your home directory to find out what commands you have been running. If you used commands like `vi filename` to open the init scripts, it will find them in the command history.